# Plotting data from an Sqlite database in tkinter

Tags: python, database, sqlite, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to plot data that has been loaded into an Sqlite database from my GUI that uses tkinter. For some reason when I run the code it takes a very long time to execute everything (even though I'm just testing this out with one plot) and it also returns an empty figure. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import sqlite3


window=tk.Tk()
conn=sqlite3.connect('Testdb.db')
CC=conn.cursor()
plt.figure()
ax1=plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)

def graph_data():
 CC.execute('SELECT Geardx, Geardy FROM Table1')
 downx=[]
 downy=[]
 for row in CC.fetchall(): 
    downx.append(row[0])
    downy.append(row[1])

plt.plot(downx,downy,'-')
plt.show()
graph_data()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You code cannot run due to `NameError: name 'downx' is not defined`.

Comment: Oh that's my mistake, I forgot to indent the "plt.plot(downx,downy,'-')" line and "plt.show()" - can you try again after indenting them to the same level as the "downx.append(row[0])" line? @acw1668

Comment: The two lines should be same level as `for` statement.  If there are data in the table, it should work fine then.